# Python Map, Lambda, and string.replace

Tags: python, string, lambda

I know how to solve my problem without using lambda/map (and I can't use regex or other python libraries for this exercise), using a for-loop with string.replace()....but I am really trying to see if I can achieve the same result using a combination of map/lambda and string.replace\

My goal here is to read in a txt file, and then substitute every instance of a non-standard 'e' (like *éêèÉÊÈ*) with the letter 'e'

My main issue now is that i get 6 lists, (e.g. I have **6 strings** in *newFile* / *newFileListComprehension* and each string has updated the original string, based on the 1 iterable that was evaluated

e.g. **newFile[0]** *= output of .replace('é')*, **newFile[1]** *= output of .replace('ê')* etc.

So what I would like, is to return 1 copy of the formatted string, with all of the .replace() iterated over it.

Link to the text file I am referencing below can be accessed https://easyupload.io/s7m0zj

````
import string

def file2str(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as fid:
        return fid.read()

def count_letter_e(filename, ignore_accents, ignore_case):
    eSToAvoid = 'éêèÉÊÈ'
    textFile = file2str("Sentence One.txt")
    newFileListComprehension = [textFile.replace(e,'e') for e in eSToAvoid if ignore_accents == 1]
    value = textFile.count('e')
    #newFile = list((map(lambda element: (textFile.replace(element, 'e') if ignore_accents == 1 else textFile.count('e')), eSToAvoid)))
    return 0

numberOfEs = count_letter_e("Sentence One.txt", 1, 1)```
````

Comment: list comprehension is very easy to adapt from your line of code. Is that what you want?

Comment: Honestly JF, I tried to use list comprehension but that seemed to work even less....and I assumed list comprehension would be more difficult because by its nature it will create an iterable list for "each" value in the list....but maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: "and I assumed list comprehension would be more difficult because by its nature it will create an iterable list for "each" value in the list." I don't know what that means, but a list comprehension is essentially a convenient way to write `map`/`filter` operations that produce lists.

Comment: In any case, you can provide an example, it is generally not well received to have these sorts of vague descriptions. Note, the fact that the data is coming from a text file isn't really relevant. Just give inputs and expected outputs, and the code you've used already. Note, just by reading your description, it doesn't sound like `map` is the correct solution to begin with. It *sounds* like it should be a `reduce`. But really, in Python, you'd just write a for-loop. Even `map` / `filter` is generally avoided where they would be appropriate.

Comment: Sure juanpa, I updated with my "attempt" at a list comprehension of this problem....i tried it, but got stuck with more or less the same results as map/reduce

Comment: No I mean your attempt with a loop. Again, **it isn't clear at all what you are even trying to accomplish**. You have to keep in mind, *we don't know what you assignment is*. A lot of what your saying doesn't make a lot of sense. file-objects don't even have those methods, so you are just working with a `str` object, presumably. That's fine, but again, what is your *exact* input, and what is your *exact, expected* output.

Comment: Ok, I thought the code was clear and my explanation, but sure i'll try to clarify in the original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209641/discussion-between-pardon-me-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Comment: Give an example that we can copy-n-paste and run.  Then we can test both your function and our own changes.  Your filename and read is useless to us.  I don't like constructing my own examples - I've done it, but it's more work, and often requires guesses.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj I just updated the original post, and included a link to the sample text file as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `str.replace` can only replace one substring with another, `re.sub` can replace a pattern.

```
In [55]: eSToAvoid = 'éêèÉÊÈ' 
In [58]: import re
```

test cases:

```
In [61]: re.sub(r'[éêèÉÊÈ]', 'e', 'foobar')                                                                          
Out[61]: 'foobar'
In [62]: re.sub(r'[éêèÉÊÈ]', 'e', eSToAvoid)                                                                         
Out[62]: 'eeeeee'
In [63]: re.sub(r'[éêèÉÊÈ]', 'e', 'testingè,É  foobar  è É')                                                         
Out[63]: 'testinge,e  foobar  e e'
```

The string replace approach is:

```
In [70]: astr = 'testingè,É  foobar  è É' 
    ...: for e in eSToAvoid: 
    ...:     astr = astr.replace(e,'e') 
    ...:                                                                                                             
In [71]: astr                                                                                                        
Out[71]: 'testinge,e  foobar  e e'
```

the replace is applied sequentially to `astr`.  This can't be expressed as a list comprehension (or `map`).  A list comprehensions most naturally replaces a loop that collects its results in a list (with `list.append`).

There's nothing wrong with the for loop.  It's actually faster:

```
In [72]: %%timeit 
    ...: astr = 'testingè,É  foobar  è É' 
    ...: for e in eSToAvoid: 
    ...:     astr = astr.replace(e,'e') 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                             
1.37 µs ± 8.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [73]: timeit re.sub(r'[éêèÉÊÈ]', 'e', 'testingè,É  foobar  è É')                                                  
2.79 µs ± 15.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [77]: timeit astr.translate(str.maketrans(eSToAvoid, 'e' * len(eSToAvoid)))                                       
2.56 µs ± 14.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

## reduce

```
In [93]: from functools import reduce  
In [96]: reduce(lambda s,e: s.replace(e,'e'),eSToAvoid, 'testingè,É  foobar  è É' )                                  
Out[96]: 'testinge,e  foobar  e e'
In [97]: timeit reduce(lambda s,e: s.replace(e,'e'),eSToAvoid, 'testingè,É  foobar  è É' )                           
2.11 µs ± 32.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For fun you could also explore some of the idea presented here:

[Cleanest way to combine reduce and map in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688133/cleanest-way-to-combine-reduce-and-map-in-python)

You want to 'accumulate' changes, and to do that, you need some sort of accumulator, something that hangs on to the last replace.  `itertools` has an `accumulate` function, and Py 3.8 introduced a `:=` walrus operator.

## generator

```
In [110]: def foo(astr, es): 
     ...:     for e in es: 
     ...:         astr = astr.replace(e,'e') 
     ...:         yield astr 
     ...:                                                                                                            
In [111]: list(foo(astr, eSToAvoid))                                                                                 
Out[111]: 
['testingè,É  foobar  è É',
 'testingè,É  foobar  è É',
 'testinge,É  foobar  e É',
 'testinge,e  foobar  e e',
 'testinge,e  foobar  e e',
 'testinge,e  foobar  e e']
```

Or `[s for s in foo(astr, eSToAvoid)]` in place of the `list()`.  This highlights that fact that a list comprehension returns a list of strings, even if the strings accumulate the changes.

Comment: great suggestion (one of my conditions was not to use regular expressions...) that being said is it fair to say that my "attempt" at using either list comprehension or lambda/map combo simply doesn't won't "work" to get the output i desire?

Comment: A list comprehension produces a list.  That's not what you want, is it?  You want a chain application, `astr.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`.  There may be some trickery that would accumulate such changes, but why?  Even in straightforward cases, a list comprehension is only mildly faster than the equivalent loop.

Comment: thanks hpaulj....the "why" is just a reflection of me learning more about python...so i thank you for your insight here

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.translate` for replacing multiple characters at once. `str.maketrans` helps you create the required mapping:

```
eSToAvoid = 'éêèÉÊÈ'
textFile.translate(str.maketrans(eSToAvoid, 'e' * len(eSToAvoid)))
```

Comment: oh my.....thank you for sharing this method. This is super clean, I need to learn a little more about how this works, but it runs well on my end :) Thanks a_guest!